# incorrect preview for excel files

Tags: finder, ms-office, preview

In finder, I previewed a file (with space bar), and saw this. Note the first few timestamps which are unexpectedly in 2020:

[image]

Opening the file in Excel to verify the error, the data is actually correct:

[image]

Is there a way to improve the preview, so it’s actually showing the correct data?